# An SNMP application is listening on port 161, how do I shut it down?

Tags: 10.04, snmp

After the installation of JIRA application on ubuntu server 10.04 64 bit server, I performed a VA (Vulnerability Assessment) on the server using NeXpol community editon. I got the VA report the app.

In the report it says I am running SNMP on the server on default port 161 UDP. How do I stop it? But in the process also its not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what JIRA is, or if it needs or installed SNMP, but...

Check that an SNMP daemon is running, and if so, on what interfaces. Open terminal and type `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 161`, which should give you something like:

```
udp    0      0 127.0.0.1:161     0.0.0.0:*       5327/snmpd
```

If you get no output, you're safe, there's no SNMP; if it says `127.0.0.1`, that's fine too, because it's only running on your local interface and cannot be accessed from outside the network.

If you do get something else, please pastebin the output of the above command and also `dpkg -l | grep -i snmp` and we can help you further in removing it.

Comment: I did not find any thing after running those commands. But how come VA Tool NeXpol is showing the SNMP is running.

Comment: NeXpol appears to be wrong, then. Can you include a screenshot or full output of NeXpol showing the problem? Because if `sudo netstat` tells you a port is closed, it *is* closed :)

Comment: Its showing like this.
Discovered Instances of this Service
Device Protocol Port Vulnerabilities Additional Information
10.9.17.31 udp 161 0

Answer (score 0):

@izx Found the solution

I had raised this issues at nexpose community too, They says https://community.rapid7.com/message/4801#4801